# Xaml: Binding a Collection within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I am very new to xaml and databinding, so please don't eat me. I am woring on a Windows 8 Store Project atm and do have some understanding problems of nested data-bindings. I'll try to structure my post as clear as possible and I am more than willing to give further imput if required.

Let's assume I have got a class structure like this:

```
public class Hotels
{
    public Collection<Hotel> HotelCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public Collection<Room> RoomCollection { get; set; }        
}

public class Room
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OccupancyMax { get; set; }
    public string OccupancyMin { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind this data to a GridView (doesn't need to be a grid view per se) like so:
[image]

I am loading the data to my Page like so (Within the HotelPageViewModel I do have an ObservableCollection of 'Hotel's -> HotelResults):

```
  var viewModel = new HotelPageViewModel();
  this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

So what I've tried so far is adding a Datatemplate to my CustomStyles.xaml. I Could post this code but that's the thing where I need help. **I don't know how to handle the Room-Collection.** I am able to show the basic Hotel-Data in my output (red part of my sketch) but how do i manage multiple Rooms within my DataTemplate (blue part)?

Code for the HotelPage.xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="HotelResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding HotelResults}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HotelPageTemplate}"         
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use a collection control, for example an `ItemsControl` setting the `ItemTemplate` to an instance of another `DataTemplate`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{HotelPageTemplate}">
    <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name"} />
       ...
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RoomCollection}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OccupancyMax}" />
                ...
             </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</DateTemplate>
```